# Sort array of objects by quarterly-yearly data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I have an array of data containing objects like below

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"Q1'2016",
      "y":0
   },
   {  
      "name":"Q2'2016",
      "y":0
   },
   {  
      "name":"Q3'2016",
      "y":0
   },
   {  
      "name":"Q4'2015",
      "y":0
   }
]
```

I want to sort them based on quarterly, so Q4'2015 should come first, then Q1'2016 and so on.

How can this be acheived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sort` method and give it a callback to sort your object based on a predicate; in your case, you want to inspect the objects' name property containing your quarter-year information. Since you'll likely have data with different quarters and years, you'll want to map the quarters to month values so you can convert them to year/month dates and compare them that way.

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "Q1'2016",
  "y": 0
}, {
  "name": "Q2'2016",
  "y": 0
}, {
  "name": "Q3'2016",
  "y": 0
}, {
  "name": "Q4'2015",
  "y": 0
}];

var quarterToMonthMap = {
  "Q1": 0,
  "Q2": 3,
  "Q3": 6,
  "Q4": 9
}

function sortByQuarterYear(lhs, rhs) {
  var lhsQuarterYear = lhs.name.split("'");
  var rhsQuarterYear = rhs.name.split("'");
  var lhsDate = new Date(lhsQuarterYear[1], quarterToMonthMap[lhsQuarterYear[0]]);
  var rhsDate = new Date(rhsQuarterYear[1], quarterToMonthMap[rhsQuarterYear[0]]);
  return lhsDate.getTime() - rhsDate.getTime();
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(data.sort(sortByQuarterYear)));
```

Comment: You can replace the `if/else if/else` with `return lhsDate.getTime() - rhsDate.getTime();`.

Comment: Good point. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To sort by year and quarter you can use the following ES6 snippet (you can do the exact same thing using ES5, but I like writing ES6)

```
input.map((obj, index) => obj.name.split("'").reverse().concat(index)).sort().map(arr => input[arr[2]]);
```

Let's break this down a bit

```
input.map((obj, index) => obj.name.split("'").reverse().concat(index))
```

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.
>   <sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map</sub>

Our "provided function" splits the "name" property of each object by the `'` character, reverses the resulting array, and adds the current index into the resulting array.

This results in an array that looks like this:

```
[
    ["2016", "Q1", 0], 
    ["2016", "Q2", 1], 
    ["2016", "Q3", 2], 
    ["2015", "Q4", 3]
]
```

Then we call `.sort`,

> The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the array. The sort is not necessarily stable. The default sort order is according to string Unicode code points.
>   <sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort</sub>

We then end up with an array like this:

```
[
    ["2015", "Q4", 3], 
    ["2016", "Q1", 0], 
    ["2016", "Q2", 1], 
    ["2016", "Q3", 2]
]
```

So we now have an appendix of sorts, notice that the indexes that we threw in there aren't in order. We can use this lack of order to create order.

All we have to do is call map again, this time returning the original object related to the index that we have stored in our temporary arrays.

```
.map(arr => input[arr[2]]);
```

When we put it all together and call it, we end up with an array like this:

```
[
    {
        name: "Q4'2015",
        y: 0
    }, {
        name: "Q1'2016",
        y: 0
    }, {
        name: "Q2'2016",
        y: 0
    }, {
        name: "Q3'2016",
        y: 0
    }
]
```

Here's a demo:

```js
let input = [  
   {  
      "name":"Q1'2016",
      "y":0
   },
   {  
      "name":"Q2'2016",
      "y":0
   },
   {  
      "name":"Q3'2016",
      "y":0
   },
   {  
      "name":"Q4'2015",
      "y":0
   }
];
    
input = input.map((obj, index) => obj.name.split("'").reverse().concat(index)).sort().map(arr => input[arr[2]]);

console.log(input);
```

To do the exact same thing in ES5:

```
input.map(function(obj, index){
    return obj.name.split("'").reverse().concat(index);
}).sort().map(function(arr){
    return input[arr[2]];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.sort()` with a comparator function, you can easily re-format each value from `"Q1'2016"` to `"2016Q1"`, allowing a simple alphanumeric comparison because `"2016Q1" > "2015Q4"`.

```js
function sortQuarters(arr) {
  function reformat(v) {
    return v.replace(/(Q\d)'(\d{4})/, "$2$1");
  }
  return arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return reformat(a.name).localeCompare(reformat(b.name));
  });
}

console.log(sortQuarters([  
   { "name":"Q1'2016", "y":0 },
   { "name":"Q3'2016", "y":0 },
   { "name":"Q2'2016", "y":0 },
   { "name":"Q4'2015", "y":0 }
]));
```

(Note that the reformatting I'm talking about is only within temporary variables used while sorting, it doesn't change the values in the array. Also note that the function I've shown modifies the order of the array passed to it and returns back the same array, it doesn't create a new array.)